# jQuery UI Autocomplete blur IE Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I can't seem to find any answers for this problem between Google and SO, and hopefully someone can go "duh, do this".

I am using blur with the UI Autocomplete to auto-select the first element in the list. This works flawlessly in Chrome, FF, and Safari. But when I use IE of any kind, it freaks out and crashes the browser. The problem lies in the following:

```
$('#element').data('selected-item');
```

I am using this to compare to the actual value in the field to make sure there was a change. That `data('selected-item')` is undefined in IE.

I was wondering if anyone had this problem in the past, or possibly know what's directly involved with this error.

This is the full code:

```
$("#element").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#element').val(ui.item.value);
        getOptions();
    },
    autoFocus: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    html: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if($('#element').val() != $('#element').data('selected-item')) {
        if($('.ui-autocomplete').length) {
            $('.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item:first-child').click();
            $('#quantity').focus();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?  https://api.jquery.com/data/   http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset HTML% data attribute is partially supported in IE8, IE9 and IE10.

Comment: IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, and IE11 are all having the eact same issue.